# inotifywait usage with rsyslog

Tags: bash, shell, inotify, inotifywait

I am trying configure inotifywait to look at my logs dir so I can send them to a logger like rsyslog and to a file.

So far I have this:

```
/usr/bin/inotifywait -e create,modify -dqs -o /newlogs /logs
```

Here are the arguments for those trying to learn this:

```
e - use following event triggers (create and modify in example)

d - daemon mode
q - quiet mode
s - send to syslog
o - output path (/newlogs)
/logs - dir to watch
```

I can see events coming into the newlogs file but the "-s" argument for syslog does not appear to be working. Can anyone help please?

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you say it isn't working?  Is syslog running?  How is syslog configured?

Comment: Yes rsyslog is running. I am expecting something related to the logs to appear in the /var/log/messages file after an event. But nothing is coming through. My rsyslog is the std one that comes with CentOS7.